# How do I add 'Licenses' to my Sidebar?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

How do I add 'Licenses' to my Sidebar?

I know how to add menu items to my Media-wiki sidebar. **'Licenses' seems to be special**. When I add 'Licenses' the menu item is missing. When I add License the text is renamed to **'Licensing:'**.

Is there a workaround? Any ideas how I can get this to work.

Comment: Can you show how you did add it?

Comment: ** licenses | Licenses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently both Licenses and License are special (cf. the wiki pages [MediaWiki:License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aLicense) and [MediaWiki:Licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aLicenses) on your own wiki - I linked to those on en.wikipedia for examples)

you can define your own with for example

** license-url | license-title

and then edit the wiki pages MediaWiki:license-url and MediaWiki:license-title

Comment: Annoying. I was able to create a page called **Licenses** just not able to add it to Sidebar menu. I could not find those **myurl/MediaWiki:License** urls you mentioned. Thanks.